# Very strange windbg behavior with WaitForSingleObject()

Tags: windbg, waitforsingleobject

Below is my program and I am trying to get the call stack when the process is blocked in WaitForSingleObject() call using windbg. The strange thing is when the process is blocking, windbg only prints out very strange stack.

```
wow64cpu!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x690
wow64cpu!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x484
wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x429
ntdll!RtlResetRtlTranslations+0x1b08
ntdll!RtlResetRtlTranslations+0xc63
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

---

```
// process2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

HANDLE g_hWriteEvent;    

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    g_hWriteEvent = OpenEvent(
        EVENT_ALL_ACCESS,
        FALSE,
        TEXT("WriteEvent")
        );

    if (g_hWriteEvent == NULL) {
        printf("OpenEvent error (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    // while (1);
    WaitForSingleObject(g_hWriteEvent, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that if I uncomment the `while(1)` line then the windbg can recognize the process is blocking in the `_tmain` function.

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: Looks like that is a Wow64 32 bit process running on 64 bit OS. Make sure you attach the 64 bit Windbg to the process, not the 32 bit Windbg.

Comment: Thanks, it is really the problem!
After I issue the 32bit switch command, the backtrace is good now!
!wow64exts.sw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is a Wow64 32 bit process running on 64 bit OS. Make sure you attach the 64 bit Windbg to the process, not the 32 bit Windbg.